# how to clear data in real-time using pusher on laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, broadcast, pusher

I have 2 routes, the first route is to display data, for example on the first page it contains 1. apple, 2 grapes
and on the second route is the page to delete data, now for example I want to delete apple data on this second page, and I want to automatically delete the deleted data on the first page without reloading in other words in real-time, how do I do it using pusher on laravel?

Answer (score 0):

when you delete the data on the second page, you can send a message through pusher to the first page, and when the first page accepts the message, you can call a route to get the latest data, then just render it on the first page.